# Transform first character in string to upcase

Tags: ruby

Is there a function (or a short bit of code) that will convert the first character in a string to uppercase without modifying other characters?

1. `abc` → `Abc`
2. `aBc` → `ABc`
3. `aBC` → `ABC`
4. `ABC` → `ABC` (no change)
5. `ABc` → `ABc` (no change)
6. `Abc` → `Abc` (no change)

Note that `String#capitalize` doesn't work in cases 2, 3, 4, and 5; it converts them to `Abc`, losing the original capitalization. (ActiveSupport's `titleize` has the same problem.)

I'd also prefer to avoid modifying the original string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-sub) with a regex to get the first char like this:

```
a = 'aBc'
a.sub(/./, &:upcase)
# => "ABc"
```

If you need you can use `sub!` and mutate the string

Comment: Succinct, comprehensible, and also handles the empty string.

Comment: `a.sub(/./, $&.upcase)` also works. ([$&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html) is a global variable containing the matched text.) `s` or `str` might be a better name name for a string, as many Rubiests use `a` for arrays, `h` for hashes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = "fOo"
newfoo = foo[0].upcase + foo[1..-1]
```

Comment: What happens if `foo = "éclair"`?

Comment: @muistooshort, There is no builtin support for upcasing unicode chars. Rails adds `mb_chars` which helps

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'unicode_utils'

"éclair".sub(/./, UnicodeUtils.upcase($&))
  #=> "Éclair"
```

Comment: As it happens, in this case I'm limited to ASCII, since the resulting string is going to be the name of a Ruby constant. But I'll definitely make a note of [unicode_utils](https://rubygems.org/gems/unicode_utils/).

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
string = "aBC".dup
string[0] = string[0].upcase
```

Comment: OP prefers to not mutate the string.